# Rosario SIS Could not Connect to Database Server

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to implement Rosariosis and installed it. I've modified the config.inc.php as per instructions.
   `$DatabaseServer = 'localhost';
    $DatabaseUsername = 'admin_user';
    $DatabasePassword = 'password';
    $DatabaseName = 'admin_db';`

But I am getting this error Failure Notice: Could not Connect to Database Server 'localhost'

I have double checked these parameters and changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and ip address but the error remains same.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please consult the [`diagnostic.php`](https://github.com/francoisjacquet/rosariosis/blob/mobile/INSTALL#L101) page for troubleshooting.

The *Could not Connect to Database Server* error usually means you have a typo in your user or password.
It can also mean the PostgreSQL server has not been started, or eventually means the server is listening on a [port](https://github.com/francoisjacquet/rosariosis/blob/mobile/INSTALL#L37) different from `5432`.